# circle with gradient background border and changing colors with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make a circular border something like this code snippet / [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q3jLaqjd/):

```css
.box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #7B73A4 0%, #150E5E 100%);
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

except the inner space needs to be transparent and there needs to be a way of changing the border's gradient color.

I can use anything with `js/jquery/css/html`

Is it possible? If yes, how? Thanks

Comment: .. added fiddle as code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using a `<canvas>` element (which is supported in all browsers except for IE 8 and older).

Here are some useful links:

- [Canvas tutorial - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_Tutorial)
- [Canvas API - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)
- [Canvas Cheat Sheet](https://simon.html5.org/dump/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html)

You could also use an SVG element, but that makes the animation much more difficult.